# text not wrapping (div tag inside a tag or vise versa)

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
      <div class="notification">A really long message blah blah blah this is a really long message loreum lipsum loreum lipsum stuff and yeah you get the point.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above works (text wraps)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
      <a href="#"><div class="notification">A really long message blah blah blah this is a really long message loreum lipsum loreum lipsum stuff and yeah you get the point.</div></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The text in the div above keeps going past the bounds of the div and off the page i added the style "x-overflow: hidden" and now it hides the text and i can scroll to see it all. but i want the text to go into a new line like normal.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leathan/njvmhnns/3/)

Comment: do you have any other CSS or `white-space` properties on `.notification`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to do it with the following.

```
.notification {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: That didnt work but white-space: pre-wrap; did, i wonder the difference?

Comment: So pre-wrap makes the wrap happen only on <br> and new line breaks but not on white space

Comment: "Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks" Thanks @mike_tung, I upvoted you but i dont have enough rep yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `word-wrap: break-word;` in the `div`

```
.notification {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that breaks words up even if they have no spaces, i tried that for the heck of it but it didnt work, ill make a jsfiddle 1 sec.